# Angular: How to covert a date string in "dd/MM/yyyy" to a date object

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime

I need to capture date data in `dd/MM/yyyy` format and need to send it to the API as Date object. I am using the following directive:

```
angular.module('tmyapp').directive('formattedDate', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            format: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from view format to model format
                return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from model format to view format
                return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
            });
        }
    }
});
//use <input type="text" formatted-date format="'dd/MM/yyyy'" />
```

It is working in showing the Date Object to `dd/MM/yyyy` but fails to convert the data in `dd/MM/yyyy` format to Date object.

Can someone help?

Comment: Parser shouldn't parse the date to return a Date object?

Comment: Right, but simply passing the data in string dd/MM/yyyy format to the date method doesn't work. I am looking for a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse date String in parser like this:

```
angular.module('tmyapp').directive('formattedDate', function (dateFilter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            format: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from view format to model format
                dateArray = data.split("/");
                var date = new Date(dateArray[2] + "-" + dateArray[1] + "-" + dateArray[0])
                return date; //converted
            });

            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (data) {
                //convert data from model format to view format
                return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So, this will make the directive work for this particular format only. And if I need to use other formats, I might have to add additional parsers. Is that right?

Comment: You can make it as conditional as you like based on the format.